# Applying Menger's theorem to a 2-connected graph to show there exist $k$ pairwise disjoint S,T paths

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a 2-connected graph. S,T are disjoint subsets of V(G) with size at least $k$. Show that there exists $k$ pairwise disjoint S,T-paths.

My current solution: Add a vertex $x$ adjacent to each vertex in S, and add a vertex
$y$ adjacent to every vertex in T. To Be Determined ...

Can I apply Menger's theorem here? If so, how?

Comment: I might be being silly here, but I'm not convinced that this is true: Let $S$ and $T$ be big complete graphs and let $s,s',t,t'$ be distinct vertices. Add an edge from $s$ to $t$ and an edge from $s'$ to $t'$. This gives a $2$-connected graph with only two $S,T$-paths.

Comment: Raoul is right. The claim is only true for $k$-connected graphs.

Comment: What claim are you disputing?

Comment: That there are necessarily more than two pairwise disjoint S,T-paths.

Comment: If the graph is k-connected rather than 2-connected then you can observe that your new graph with $x$ and $y$ added is still k-connected, which means that you can apply Menger's theorem to get $k$ (internally) disjoint paths from $x$ and $y$. You should be able to adjust these paths to give the ones that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well post it as an answer. See my comment for why $2$-connectedness isn't sufficient.

> Let $G$ be a **k**-connected graph. $S,T$ are disjoint subsets of $V(G)$ with size at least $k$. Show that there exists $k$ pairwise disjoint $S,T$-paths.
>
> Add a vertex $x$ adjacent to each vertex in $S$, and add a vertex $y$ adjacent to every vertex in $T$.

$x$ and $y$ are both adjacent to at least $k$ vertices, so the new graph is $k$-connected.

By Menger's theorem there exist at least $k$ internally disjoint paths from $x$ to $y$.

Say one of these paths is $xv_1 \ldots v_ny$. Let $v_j$ be the first of these vertices that is in $T$ and $v_i$ be the last of these vertices that is in $S$ such that $i<j$. Then $v_i \ldots v_j$ is an $S,T$-path.

We can do this to each of the $\geq k$ paths. Since the original paths were internally disjoint, the reduced paths must be disjoint as required.