A graph $G$ is $2$-connected if and only if there exist two disjoint $S,T$-paths.
I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Let $G$ be a graph with at least $4$ vertices. Then $G$ is $2$-connected if and only if, for any two disjoint $S, T \subseteq V(G)$, satisyfing $|S|, |T| \geq 2$ there exists two completely vertex disjoint $S,T$-paths, each with no internal vertices in $S \cup T$.

I have made an attempt at both implications.
$\bullet$ For the left to right implication we may add distinct dummy vertices $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ is adjacent to all of $S$ and $y$ is adjacent to all of $T$. The graph $G$ with $x$, $y$ and their edges added is still $2$-connected. By Menger's theorem there exists a pair of internally vertex disjoint $x, y$-paths, say $P_{1}= (x = v_{0}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{k} = y)$ and $P_{2} = (x = w_{0}, w_{1}, \dots, w_{l} = y)$. By construction $v_{1}, w_{1} \in S$ and $v_{k-1}, w_{l-1} \in T$. If we remove $x$ and $y$ from $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ we are left with two completely vertex disjoint $S, T$-paths.
I came across similar reasoning in another post, my question is how (or if) we can guarantee that the paths do not have internal vertices in $S \cup T$.
$\bullet$ For the right to left implication, suppose that $G$ is not $2$-connected. Then $G$ has a cut vertex $v \in V(G)$. Let $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ be two components of $G-v$. Let $S \subseteq C_{1}$ and $T \subseteq C_{2}$ such that $|S|, |T| \geq 2$. Any path from a vertex in $C_{1}$ to a vertex in $C_{2}$ must go through $v$ in $G$. By assumption there exists two completely disjoint $S, T$-paths with no internal vertices in $S \cup T$, but this contradicts the fact that these paths must share the cut vertex $v$.
This reasoning seems okay, my question is how (or if) we can guarantee that the components $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ of $G-v$ both have at least two vertices.
Any help is appreciated.
Edit: to clarify, by an $S,T$ path I mean a path from some vertex in $S$ to a vertex in $T$.

What is an "$S,T$-path"? Is it a path from some vertex in $S$ to some vertex in $T$?

This answer actually addresses your first question how to guarantee that no internal vertices are in $S\cup T$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/973591/715329

For the right-to-left implication, you can again use Menger's theorem with $S={v}$ and $T={w}$, where $v,w$ are any two distinct vertices in $G$.

@Pranay 1. Yes thank you, I've added a clarification. 2. This is what I thought initially as well, but in the problem the existence of these completely disjoint $S,T$-paths is only guaranteed for $|S|, |T| \geq 2$.

Ah yes, sorry I missed that condition. Just to make sure, the only solved question now is the right-to-left implication?

^ I meant to say "unsolved"

@Pranay Yes (more or less).

For the right-to-left implication:
Let us assume that $G$ is not $2$-connected. Then we just have to show that there are disjoint $S$ and $T$ with $|S|,|T|\ge2$ such that there is at most one vertex disjoint $S,T$-path with internal vertices outside $S\cup T$. To show this, we proceed as the OP did: we remove the cut vertex $v$ from $G$, and let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be a nonempty bipartition of the remaining vertices so that there is no edge between them in $G\setminus v$ (note that $C_1$ and $C_2$ don't have to be connected).

If $|C_1|,|C_2|\ge2$, take $S=C_1$ and $T=C_2$. Any $S,T$-path must go through $v$ in $G$.
If $|C_1|=1$ (which means $|C_2|\ge2$), then take $S=C_1\cup v$ and $T=C_2$, so that $|S|,|T|\ge2$. There is clearly a path from $v$ to $T$ with a single edge. For another $S,T$-path to be vertex disjoint from this path, it must start from the other vertex in $S$ and not include $v$. But this is impossible.

Either way, we exhibited $S$ and $T$ where there is at most one vertex disjoint path with no internal vertices in $S\cup T$, so we are done.

Thank you this is very clear. I'm still unsure why, for the left to right implication, the paths do not have any internal vertices in $S \cup T$. Why is it that the paths $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ (as described in the post) can't go through another vertex in $S$ before leaving it?

@JLGL Say the path $P_1$ is given by $x,v_1,\ldots,v_n,y$, where $x$ and $y$ are the added vertices. We know that $v_1\in S$ and $v_n\in T$. Here’s the key idea: pick the vertex $v_j$ that enters $T$ for the first time in the path, i.e., for any $k<j$, $v_k\notin T$, but $v_j\in T$. Then, in the path $v_1,\ldots,v_j$, pick the vertex $v_i$ that exits $S$ for the last time, i.e., for any $i<k\le j$, $v_k\notin S$, but $v_i\in S$. The path $v_i,\ldots,v_j$ is an $S,T$-path with no internal vertices in $S \cup T$.
